# How to read input text ? Java

Tags: java, string, eclipse

I need to check if a "user" types in the word "if". Let me explain, i have this:
String text;

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("type text");
text=read.nextLine();
System.out.println("the text is " +text);
```

I need to make sure that what is typed in is a the word "if".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the value of text with the value if using `equals()` like this:

```
if(text.equals("if")){
   //Do something
}
```

Or a better null safe solution would be:

```
if("if".equals(text)){}
```

This way if text is null your program won't crash
Thanks to @Tancho for the null safe sollution
Generally speaking to compare 2 string you need to use `equals()`
Using `==` you compare 2 objects references not the values

Comment: Please do "if".equals(text) which is null safe.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API's [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) or [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) methods as shown below:

```
if(text.contains("if ") || text.contains(" if") || text.contains(" if ")) {
    System.out.println(" Text contains if");
}
```

The above code works even if the word `if` is at the start or at the end of the input `text`.

If you are looking for **the whole word match, then you need to use [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))** as shown below:

```
if(text.equals("if")) {
    System.out.println(" Text equals if");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an exact match, you should use :

```
"if".equals(text)
```

Not the other way around, because a constant should always be compared to a variable, not the other way around. 
You will have : 
1. readability 
2. safety (as this will never throw a NullPointerException, even if text is null)